# Laravel 5.3 on Ubuntu 18.04, Post requests are not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel(V5.3) application On Ubuntu 18.04. All routes work well on my localhost (windows) but in the live server the POST requests returns

> "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

If you submit, it will return the above message.

I have following values in .env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

I cleared route, config, cache. I tried composer dumpautoload

I checked laravel.log - No errors. I checked the PHP error file - No errors

Comment: Did anything got written to your PHP error log file?

Comment: I executed nano /var/log/apache2/error.log  and its empty.

Comment: Is this the correct error file? What does the php.ini variable `error_log` say?

Comment: not sure how to find it :(

Comment: All the variables will be displayed with the `phpinfo()` function. Just search for the one that says `error_log`.

Comment: display_errors=off and error_log=null

Comment: Oh. Are you in a production system?

Comment: Yes I am on production

Comment: You might want to turn the logging of errors on. Can you debug the app somewhere else, not especially in a production system?

Comment: Did it ever work on Ubuntu? Have you tried to increase permissions of your server process?

Comment: Not tried that, this is the client's server. I enabled error_log, but no logs in the error file.

Comment: php artisan route:clear

Comment: thanks but I already tried this.

Comment: @Dan I set an error_log file. An error in a simple php file logs the correct error. but the above message is not logging any errors.